# Use same variable multiple times in a Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, variables, dockerfile

I'm trying to use the same variable (`$MINERV`) multiple times in the following Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:stable

ARG MINERV=5.5c

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN mkdir /home/docker
RUN curl "https://github.com/PhoenixMinerDevTeam/PhoenixMiner/releases/download/$MINERV/PhoenixMiner_$MINERV_Linux.tar.gz" -L -o "/home/docker/PhoenixMiner_$MINERV_Linux.tar.gz"

WORKDIR /home/docker

CMD ["ls"]
```

The output for `docker build . -t test && docker run test` is `PhoenixMiner_.tar.gz` when I'm expecting `PhoenixMiner_5.5c_linux.tar.gz`

I can confirm the `curl` is trying to grab `https://github.com/PhoenixMinerDevTeam/PhoenixMiner/releases/download/5.5c/PhoenixMiner_$MINERV_Linux.tar.gz` as well. I've also tried it with `ENV` instead of `ARG` to the same result.

How can I use the same variable multiple times in a Dockerfile?

Thanks!

Comment: Not related to your question, but note that the structure of your Dockerfile is going to lead to lots of wasted space in your image. Group all your `apt` commands into a single `RUN` statement and clean up the cache at the end.

Comment: The problem is that `_` is a valid character in a variable name, so when your write `$MINERV_Linux.tar.gz`, Docker is looking for a variable named `MINERV_Linux`.  @enriqueponce has the solution.

Comment: *facepalm* yes it is! Thank you both! Knew it would end up being something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have to put $MINERV like this -> ${MINERV} where you are using it